# Webpack - Issue with importing generic file into a large codebase

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a file called 'third_party.js' which is shown below.  I would like to have this brought into an existing webpack app (not by using imports or requires in my codebase - but webpack only).  As you can see, the IIFE needs window and $ for this to work.  I have many .btns in my app that can be clicked on and was hoping there was an easy way to handle this from a global level.

**third_party.js**

```
(function (window, $) {

  $(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("button was clicked");
    });
  });

})(window, jQuery);
```

Comment: not sure but try this`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 'window.third_party': 'path/to/third_party.js' });`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this file into the `entry` of your Webpack.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        '/path/to/third_party.js',
        'path/to/original/file.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: 'path/to/output/dir',
        name: 'bundle.js'
    },
    ...
};
```

Make sure you have jQuery loaded in a script tag on the page before you include the Webpack bundle file (your Webpack output).

Something like:

```
<script src="cdn.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/output/dir/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is loading the third_party.js script into the bundle, however the click binding does not seem to be working.  I am using aureliajs as the framework.  When I output to console $(".btn") via script, it shows a length of 0 even though I have some .btns.  If I type in $(".btn") to the console after the page is loaded, I see a length > 0.

Comment: It sounds like your buttons are being injected using Javascript? If this is the case, you can either bind the IIFE to an 'done' event when aureliasjs has added the buttons, or put the script tag with the bundle.js at the very end of your document, e.g. before </body>